# log4net with firebird database

Tags: c#, web-config, log4net, firebird

Is there a possibility to use log4net with firebird database? In the web.config file I have:

```
<configSections>
<section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
</configSections>
<log4net>
  <appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
   <connectionType value="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FirebirdClientFactory, FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient, Version=3.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3750abcc3150b00c" />
  <connectionString value="my connection string for firebird" />
  <commandText value="INSERT INTO NETS_LOG (WHO,TYPE) VALUES (@log_who, @log_type)" />

  <parameter>
  <parameterName value="@log_who" />
  <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="255" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%logger" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@log_type" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="50" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%level" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
</appender>
<root>
  <level value="ALL" />
  <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender" />
</root>
```

In addition in the method Application_Start() I have:

```
var logConfigFilePath = Server.MapPath("~/Web.config");
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new System.IO.FileInfo(logConfigFilePath));
```

When I add log, I don't see an entry in the database:

```
log.Debug("sssss");
```

## Edit

I enabled debug for log4net and I changed ConnetionType to :

```
<connectionType value="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FirebirdClientFactory, FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient, Version=3.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3750abcc3150b00c" />
```

Now, I have error:

```
log4net:ERROR [AdoNetAppender] ErrorCode: GenericFailure. Could not open database  connection [Server=***;user  id=***;password=***;Charser=ANSI_CHARSET;***]. Connection string context [ConnectionString].
System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly,  Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean&  bNeedSecurityCheck)
at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
at log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender.CreateConnection(Type connectionType, String connectionString)
at log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender.InitializeDatabaseConnection()
```

Comment: Is the Firebird project reference set to `Copy Local = true`? Also, you can set log4net to use debug mode by setting `<log4net debug=true>` in the config file, which might help diagnose the problem.

Comment: Also you're specifying the type of the connection without specifying the assembly it comes from: normally there would be something like `<connectionType value="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient, FirebirdSql.Data, Version=...>`

Comment: I'd say your use of `FirebirdClientFactory` is wrong, I think it should be `FbConnection`